# When to create a new document in NoSQL

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I've just starting out with NoSQL (in my case CouchDB) and can't seem to answer what I believe should be a simple question, on what the common practice is around creating a new document vs. appending data to an existing one.

I currently have a database per user (meaning that I can give users access ONLY to the data they own).

So at the top level, my CouchDB looks like:

> - UserA_db
> - UserB_db

Say I have a simple notebook application, where each user can have 1 or more notebooks, each containing 1 or more notes.

**Is the idea that you add a single document per notebook, like so:**

> - UsersA_db
>
>   - NoteBook1_doc = { notes: [ { notebody: 'foo' }, { notebody: 'bar'} ] }
>   - NoteBook2_doc = { notes: [ { notebody: 'baz' }, { notebody: 'boo'} ] }

**OR, is *everything* supposed to be completely flat, irrespective of what the document *is*, what it *contains* or what it *relates to*?**

> - UsersA_db
>
>   - NoteBook1_doc = { id: 1 }
>   - Note1_doc { id: 1, parentBook: 1, notebody: 'foo' }
>   - Note2_doc { id: 2, parentBook: 1, notebody: 'bar' }
>   - SomethingCompletelyDifferent_doc { id: 1, text: 'all cows eat grass' }
>   - AccountInformation_doc { name: 'Bob', age: 34 }

Comment: Object composition almost always comes down to taste, not hard facts. If you have more experience in object design in the application itself, it may be a good idea to start off there and keep the database structure similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could go either way, but a useful fact to remember is that documents are the unit of atomic transactions in CouchDB. You an make an atomic, transactional change to data in CouchDB if *all* the data is within one document.

Also, recall that CouchDB *views* are called "views" because they let you *see* your data in various ways, in a completely consistent state. Views always represent a point-in-time snapshot of the data at the time you request them. Views can also [collate data](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation) together. A view could, for example, show you a notebook by collating together the individual notes.

Joachim is right that this is a judgement call, but personally I would lean more towards your second option: every note is a document.